# How do I translate a name?

Tags: translation, nouns

Suppose I want to translate an Italian name like *Guglielmo*. Do I first translate it in a language with a pronunciation closer to Esperanto (for example, *William* in English), or do I adapt it directly from Italian?
Should I translate it in a specific language, before translating it to Esperanto? *Guglielmo* comes from the Germanic *Willihelm* or *Willahelm*. Does that mean I should translate it to German, and then in Esperanto?

In the specific example I made, the Esperanto *Vilhelmo* is closer to the Danish (or Swedish) *Vilhelm*.

Comment: I think it's not really translation it's adaptation for convenience

Comment: I mean _translate_ as in _get the word in a language given a word in another language_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When *transliterating* names you always have two choices: Do you want to approximate the way the name sound as closely as possible, or do you want to closely match the way the name is written? You usually want to have the former for personal names, but the latter may be useful, lest the name become unrecognizable (for city's this might be convenient).

In this case, since it's a personal name, I would just try to match the sounds as closely as possible. As far as I know, *Guglielmo* is pronounced more or less like [ɡuˈʎɛlmo], which I would transliterate to *Guljelmo*. There is no reason to first convert the name to English or another language.

However, if you're transliterating the name of a foreign, usually famous, person, I would recommend transliterating the name from the original language and not the Italianized name. So if there is some Dutch person called Wilhelm /ˈʋɪlɦɛlm/ and you use the name Guglielmo in Italian, then don't transliterate this to *Guljelmo*, but use the original Dutch name to obtain *Vilhelmo* or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are free to use the original spelling name, use a transliteration as [commented by Joffysloffy](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/571/how-do-i-translate-a-name/573#573) or use the most common variant in Esperanto. You can find variants of some names on Wikipedia.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_(given_name)#Etymology) is written that the Italian name *Guglielmo* is a variant of the old Germanic name *Wilhelm*. The variant for Esperanto shown there is [*Vilhelmo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_(given_name)#Name_variants).

Some other examples on Wikipedia:

- [Elizabeth - *Elizabeto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_(given_name)#Name_variants)
- [Carolina - *Karolina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolina_(name)#Variants_of_the_name)
- [James, Jacob - *Jakobo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_(name)#Cognates)